# Scala Map indexed by Type

Tags: scala

I'm trying to make an `Set`-like that accepts only one entry for each subtype of a `trait`. My code is currently:

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

trait Component
case class Entity(id: Int)

case class ComponentA(some: String) extends Component
case class ComponentB(other: Int) extends Component
case class ComponentC(thing: Boolean) extends Component

val components: Map[Entity, Set[Component]] = Map(Entity(1) -> Set(ComponentA("A"), ComponentB(1)))
def getComponent[A <: Component: ClassTag](entity: Entity): Option[A] = {
  components.getOrElse(entity, Nil).collectFirst { case c: A => c }
}

getComponent[ComponentA](Entity(1))
getComponent[ComponentB](Entity(1))
getComponent[ComponentC](Entity(1))
```

My list of entities will be in the millions, but the components for each entity will be ~100. Is there a faster way, with some type indexed map, to prevent the *O(n)* `collectFirst` on every read, and a `filter` + `append` for each update?

I tried a number of things, but the closest I could get is create a `ComponentType` trait that is used for the `Map[ComponentType, Component]` key, and then have the `getComponent` method return a generic `Component` instead of the actual requested type. This leaves me to type cast at runtime or pattern match for each caller instead of have the compiler cast it for me.

Any other combinations with types, enumerations, maybe a specialized `Set` or `Map` type that can help here?

Maybe all the type checking is not worth the overhead of doing only 100/2 iterations on average, but I have nothing to compare performance against.

Comment: I wouldn't bother with performance optimizations before determining that there is an actual performance problem.

Comment: That's absolutely true. My current implementation runs slower than I'd like but I haven't determined this is the/a cause just yet. But I do find it frustrating that I can't get this exact same method signature to work with a different underlying collection type. So I'm still trying to figure out _why_ :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can avoid creating a `ComponentType` trait by using a `Map[ClassTag[_], Component]` for the second level structure:

```
val components: Map[Entity, Map[ClassTag[_], Component]] = Map(
  Entity(1) -> Map(
    implicitly[ClassTag[ComponentA]] -> ComponentA("A"), 
    implicitly[ClassTag[ComponentB]] -> ComponentB(1))
)

def getComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = {
  components.getOrElse(entity, Map[ClassTag[_], Component]()).get(tag).asInstanceOf[Option[A]]
}
```

The same way you can implement `addComponent`:

```
def addComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity, component: A)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Map[Entity, Map[ClassTag[_], Component]] = {
  components + (entity -> (components.getOrElse(entity, Map[ClassTag[_], Component]()) + (tag -> component)))
}
```

You could not avoid casting this way, but if you hide the implementation of your `components` map in a class `Components`, then you can be pretty safe I think:

```
class Components {
  private val components: Map[Entity, Map[ClassTag[_], Component]] = Map()
  def getComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = ???
  def addComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity, component: A)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Components = ???
}
```

**Update**:
Based on @RüdigerKlaehn's comment, I modified the code, it's more readable now:

```
val components: Map[(Entity, ClassTag[_]), Component] = Map(
  (Entity(1), implicitly[ClassTag[ComponentA]]) -> ComponentA("A"),
  (Entity(1), implicitly[ClassTag[ComponentB]]) -> ComponentB(1)
)

def getComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Option[A] = {
  components.get((entity, tag)).asInstanceOf[Option[A]]
}

def addComponent[A <: Component](entity: Entity, component: A)(implicit tag: ClassTag[A]): Map[(Entity, ClassTag[_]), Component] = {
  components + ((entity, tag) -> component)
}
```

Comment: Why not use a (Entity, ClassTag[_]) tuple as a key of a single level map if you want to do this?

Comment: In my case, I both want to iterate over all components sometimes (I don't know what I'm looking for), and sometimes get a single one (I know what I'm looking for). But it's a very valid suggestion, maybe I'll end up doing just that and refactor the other bits.

Comment: @RüdigerKlaehn because I haven't thought about, but it looks good